# Breakout from 400Gbps to n*25Gbps

Tags: cisco, juniper, fiber, cisco-nexus

My servers are currently have 25Gbps NIC, but switch ( Cisco Nexus 9300 series) has only 400Gbps.

I would like to be able to break out the 400Gbps connection into four 25Gbps connections. Is this possible? If not, what are my other options?

Comment: What Nexus 9300 switch supports 400G?

Comment: The 9300 GX and 9300 GX2 models do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**

According to [this page](https://www.cisco.com/c/m/en_us/products/switches/nexus-9000-series-switches/nb-06-nexus-9300-32port-400g-ig-cte-en.html), each port of the Nexus 9300 is breakout capable.

You can configure the interface with the `interface breakout module` command.

Of course you will need the ad-hoc cable.

It is not obvious from [this page from Cisco](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/interfaces-modules/transceiver-modules/whitepaper-c11-744077.html) that you can goes from 400G to 25G (only 400 -> 100 is listed), however, in [this guide](https://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/products/collateral/interfaces-modules/transceiver-modules/cabling-guide-400g-qsfp.pdf) in scenario 7 and 8, the 400G to 25G options are cited:

[image]

Comment: Just FYI, this solution is not a direct breakout cable and requires additional components (i.e. #2 is an MTP cartridge).

If OP needs direct breakout from 400G to 25G, it's standardized as IEEE802.3bs (400GBASE-SR16). Sadly no network vendors support it (yet) and no transceiver vendors sell it (yet).

Comment: @JordanHead thanks for the info. I routinely do 100->4x25 but doesn't work with 400G yet.

Comment: Right, I meant if the interface is strictly 400G vs a multirate one that you can set at 100 and break out from there without additional stuff (i.e. just a breakout cable).

Answer (score 2):

That's possible.

Assuming an N9K-C9316D-GX, 9364D-GX2A, 9348D-GX2A, or 9332D-GX2B:

> Breakout supported on all ports, 1-16: 2x200, 4x100, 2x100, 8x50,
> 4x50, 2x50, **4x25**, 4x10

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/switches/nexus-9000-series-switches/nexus-9300-gx-series-switches-ds.html

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/switches/nexus-9000-series-switches/datasheet-c78-743854.html

According to the [Breakout Cable Ordering Guide](https://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/products/collateral/interfaces-modules/transceiver-modules/fiber-optic-trans.pdf), for instance a QSFP-100G-SR4-S should be able to connect to 25GBASE-SR modules on the server side, using an appropriate optical breakout cable or harness (MPO12↔4x2xLC MMF).

Using a DAC breakout could also be possible but might cause compatibility options with your server NICs. I'd stick to fiber.